# Spark Datasets - Inner Join Issue

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I am using Spark 2.0.0 and I have two datasets (Dataset[Row]) as follows.

Dataset 'appUsage':

```
+----------+-------------------+----------+
|DATE      |APP_ID             |TIMES_USED|
+----------+-------------------+----------+
|2016-08-03|06xgKq10eeq0REK4eAc|null      |
|2016-08-03|ssads2wsdsf        |null      |
|2016-08-03|testApp            |null      |
|2016-08-03|3222aClie-971837083|5         |
|2016-08-03|V2aadingTLV02      |null      |
|2016-08-03|OurRating-985443645|5         |
|2016-08-03|Trdssktin-743439164|null      |
|2016-08-03|myaa1-app          |null      |
|2016-08-03|123123123-013663450|null      |
+----------+-------------------+----------+
```

Dataset 'appDev'

```
+-------------------+------------------------------------+
|APP_ID             |DEVELOPER_ID                        |
+-------------------+------------------------------------+
|OurRating-985443645|5fff25c7-6a70-4d54-ad04-197be4b9a6a9|
|Xa11d0-560090096095|5fff25c7-6a70-4d54-ad04-197be4b9a6a9|
+-------------------+------------------------------------+
```

When I do a left join using the following code, it all works as expected.

```
val result = appUsage.join(appDev, Seq("APP_ID"), "left")
```

Output is:

```
+-------------------+----------+----------+------------------------------------+
|APP_ID             |DATE      |TIMES_USED|DEVELOPER_ID                        |
+-------------------+----------+----------+------------------------------------+
|06xgKq10eeq0REK4eAc|2016-08-03|null      |null                                |
|ssads2wsdsf        |2016-08-03|null      |null                                |
|testApp            |2016-08-03|null      |null                                |
|3222aClie-971837083|2016-08-03|5         |null                                |
|V2aadingTLV02      |2016-08-03|null      |null                                |
|OurRating-985443645|2016-08-03|5         |5fff25c7-6a70-4d54-ad04-197be4b9a6a9|
|Trdssktin-743439164|2016-08-03|null      |null                                |
|myaa1-app          |2016-08-03|null      |null                                |
|123123123-013663450|2016-08-03|null      |null                                |
+-------------------+----------+----------+------------------------------------+
```

But I want to do an inner join so that only the rows that are present in both datasets will be part of the resultset. However, when I do it using the following code, the output is empty.

```
val result = appUsage.join(appDev, Seq("APP_ID"), "inner")
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
val result = appUsage.join(appDev, "APP_ID")
```

I tried it on `Databrics cloud` with `Spark 2.0.0` and it worked fine.

Please refer [this](https://databricks-prod-cloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/public/4027ec902e239c93eaaa8714f173bcfc/2913118825018822/436258942993707/1658806086977529/latest.html).

Comment: The problem was not with the join specifically. I was building the 'appUsage' DataSet above using a series of outer joins. Seems like Spark optimizer is changing the order of the joins or something that causes this issue. I will ask that as a separate question. When I change that outer join to left join, appUsage.join(appDev, Seq("APP_ID"), "inner") works as well. Thanks for the help!